# Ground Wire to Prevent Static Discharge

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I'm part of the robotics team at my school, and we built a robot for the competition. To prevent static discharge from the chassis to the circuit, we attached a wire from the negative side of the DC power supply to the metal chassis. I asked my mentor why we did this, and he told me that as the mats on the floor add electrons to the metal chassis, the electronics build up potential relative to the chassis, given that the chassis is more negative than the negative side of the DC. So we bond the chassis to the circuit ground to even out the potential to prevent arcing.

My question:
Why keep the potential difference between the metal chassis and the negative DC the same? Why not attach a grounding wire from the chassis to the positive side of the DC? Because relative to the chassis, which has a lot of static electrons built up, BOTH the negative and the positive have potential/voltage, so why only ground between negative and chassis?

Comment: Do you mean ground the positive and not the negative, or ground positive as well as negative?

Comment: By convention, all U.S. automobiles (that I know of) ground the negative side of the battery to the car body.  I suspect your mentor is just following this convention.

Comment: @JohnDarby That is exactly what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

Grounding the negative side of the DC-powered circuit is more a matter of a convention.

You can ground either and get the same effect.

The chasis will not be able to achieve a thousands or tens of thousands of volts static potential difference from your circuit, so no sparks possible.

The convention about grounding the negative side brings two benefits that may or may not be important:

1. One can clip the negative voltmeter conductor to the chasis and measure voltages in the circuit. This way, one will almost always get positive measurements. Most electronics are negative-ground, too.
2. In some cases, involving different metals, intermittent moisture and/or other factors, the electric potential affects corrosion. The chassis is somewhat safer against corrosion when connected to the negative (the positive voltage promotes the electrical conductor's corrosion, but the conductors are easier to replace than the chassis.

The effect is quite visible in marine and automotive environment. A lot of retro cars built pre-1965 have positive chassis. 50-60 years later the wires are "like new", but the steel around them is... well, worse than "like new".

Comment: Here's a picture of my team's robot and the floor: https://imgur.com/a/VQaccrF. so if the chassis has a huge static buildup from the mats and you tie your positive to chassis (unconventional way), how does that change the potential differences between positive and chassis and positive and negative? And what happens if the same happens but with negative tied to chassis? John Darby tried to illustrate this in a picture but I didn't understand it all...

Comment: With the + end grounded, electrons briefly flow until the potential of the + end is that of ground.   With the - end grounded, electrons briefly flow until the potential of the - end is that of ground.  The emf maintains the potential difference between the + and - ends the same.  I updated my discussion of my simple figure.  Hope this helps. @fraxinus, maybe you can explain it more clearly.

Comment: @JohnDarby I slept on this and it all makes sense. Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can ground either positive or negative end of the power supply and electrons will temporarily flow until the electrical potential at that end becomes the same as the electrical potential of the ground; the potential of the other end of the power supply will maintain the same difference relative to the grounded end as it originally maintained relative to the non-grounded end.  The non-grounded situation is sometimes called a "floating" power supply, in contrast to the "grounded" power supply.

If you ground both ends of the power supply, you short out the power supply; electrons will flow to try and create equal potential at both ends of the supply until the protective elements (circuit breaker or fuse) trip to prevent overloading and burning out the power supply.

*Updated response to your comment.* With one end of the power supply grounded (either end), electrons flow between the grounded end and the ground to equalize the electrical potential between that end and the ground.  Inside the power supply, the electromotive force (emf) used to maintain the potential difference between the ends of the power supply (battery chemical reactions, generator action, whatever) results in charges being redistributed internally in the power supply as necessary to *maintain the same potential difference* between the two ends whether one end is grounded or not.  Yes, the *potential of the ungrounded end relative to ground* can be different than the ground potential if the other end is not grounded, but the *potential difference between the two ends* is the same whether one end is grounded or not.

See the following example; the box indicates the power supply, the top is the + end voltage and the bottom is the - end voltage.  Three conditions are shown: power supply ungrounded (with floating potentials $V+$ and $V-$), negative end grounded, and positive end grounded. The potential of the grounded end of the power supply changes from its floating potential to equal the ground potential $Vgnd$ but the potential difference between the two ends of the power supply, $\Delta V$, does not change, no matter which end of the power supply is grounded.
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to bond positive to chassis in the case of something with very high voltage because you don't want to be in contact with very high potential but rather with very minimal potential like the circuit ground/negative.

Comment: "the potential of the other end of the power supply will maintain the same difference relative to the grounded end as it originally maintained relative to the non-grounded end." How is this true? In the case of our awful static-electricity-rich floor mats, if my negative side gains potential because it came in contact with a static-electricity-rich mat via the ground wire, doesn't the positive side gain even more potential than it had before? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to say.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Hope this helps.

Comment: "Yes, the potential of the ungrounded end relative to ground can be different than the ground potential if the other end is not grounded." First, when you say relative to ground, are you referring to the circuit ground/negative, or you referring to my floor mats? Second, I can't figure out what "can be different than the ground potential if the other end is not grounded" means.

Comment: "can be different than the ground potential if the other end is not grounded." My head hurts trying to understand this. We started off the sentence talking about the non-grounded end and compared it to the ground potential... of the non-grounded end?

Comment: The mat can build up charge due to friction; connecting the mat to the metal chassis and the chassis to ground and one side of the power supply to the chassis prevents charge build up (potential  difference) that could cause an arc between the mat/chassis/power supply.  This also forces the grounded end of the power supply to be at the same potential as ground.  The other end of the power supply maintains the same potential difference relative to the grounded end as previously described, even though the potential of the grounded end can change once grounded.

Comment: Without a grounding wire, the chassis could build up potential difference relative to the mats and that could cause a dangerous HV arc from mats to the chassis, then from chassis to the power supply. With the grounding wire, the power supply maintains the same potential as the chassis so there's no arcing. And no matter what, my battery will always have 12v of potential between the un-grounded positive and the grounded negative. Am I saying all of this correctly?

Comment: Yes! Please see the drawing I added.

Comment: Here's a picture of my team's robot and the floor: imgur.com/a/VQaccrF. so if the chassis has a huge static buildup from the mats and you tie your positive to chassis (unconventional way), how does that change the potential differences between positive and chassis and positive and negative? And what happens if the same happens but with negative tied to chassis? I see you tried to illustrate this in a picture but I didn't understand it all... (I do know what delta means btw.) I went over it with an engineer but he didn't quite understand either...

Comment: $\Delta$ means difference.  $\Delta V$ is the voltage difference between the two ends of the power supply, and this difference in voltage is the same if you ground either + or - end of the power supply; the grounded end goes to the ground potential and the other end adjusts to keep $\Delta V$ constant.   My picture shows three cases: ungrounded, - end grounded, and + end grounded. Also, see the response by @fraxius.

Answer (score 0):

Because electric current is due  to the flow of electrons which carries negative charge